# Why LabelBinarizer from sklearn is slow or not?

Tags: python, performance, scikit-learn

I am trying to compare performance of `LabelBinarizer` from `sklearn` with simple dictionary:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelBinarizer
import time

sample_list = list('abcdefg')
lb = LabelBinarizer()
lb.fit(dep_tag_list)
lb_t = lb.transform(sample_list)
sample_dict = {key:value for (key,value) in zip(sample_list, lb_t)}
```

This code ran: --- 2.9169740676879883 seconds ---

```
start_time = time.time()
result = lb.transform(sample_list*1000000)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

And this code ran: --- 0.6299951076507568 seconds ---

```
start_time = time.time()
result = [sample_dict[el] for el in sample_list*1000000]
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Am I comparing apples to apples? Why LableBinarizer is so slow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LabelBinarizer is a wrapper over [label_binarize](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.label_binarize.html). And may also be used in some other scikit utilities internally. So it needs to take care that the data passed to it is appropriate.

For this, it performs multiple checks on the passed data. Please look at the source code of [`transform()` function here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L309):

```
y_is_multilabel = type_of_target(y).startswith('multilabel')
if y_is_multilabel and not self.y_type_.startswith('multilabel'):
    raise ValueError("The object was not fitted with multilabel"
                     " input.")

return label_binarize(y, self.classes_,
                      pos_label=self.pos_label,
                      neg_label=self.neg_label,
                      sparse_output=self.sparse_output)
```

So you see its checking if the passed `y` is of suitable type which can be handled by scikit algorithms or not. After that data is passed to `label_binarize` whose [source code is](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py#L390), which perform other additional checks on it. In my opinion this is the reason for its slowness.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I guess it is more appropriate to compare it to get_dummies from pandas. get_dummies is still way faster

Comment: @user1700890 Because get_dummies will still not do all those checks that I mentioned

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. get_dummies is way faster than labelbinarizer

Comment: @user1700890 Yes I know.  get_dummies is faster because it dont do all those checks that LabelBinarizer does that I mentioned